# javascript automatic parallelism

Tags: javascript, multithreading, openmp, web-worker

I know this could be flagged as off-topic, but let's try. I didn't find any answer elsewhere and my attempts would be to modify v8 or any JavaScript interpreter by hand, which looks quite a bit of work...

I wonder if there is any existing tool to automate parallelism for JavaScript (or any superset language).

What I'd like is basically an openmp #pragma'ish language which could generate workers and postmessage mess for me.

I know there exist libraries which allow parallel.for'ish code, but ideally I'd like to find a tool based on comments/decorators/directives.

Comment: You're right. It is off-topic. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: I know and I'm moderating a bit myself, but I didn't find any answer elsewhere. I hope to find an expert or yet internal project

Comment: [Parralel.js](https://adambom.github.io/parallel.js/) maybe?

Comment: @MikeC yet i've seen some questions that specfically ask for a "book" and get 1k+ upvotes....